# Root LinearLayout does not allign center

Tags: android, android-layout, nested

[image: Nexus 5 emulator image]

The Root code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/satranc"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/boy"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

The root tag is closed. Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The orientation of your LinearLayout is vertical and you have set the gravity to center_horizontal. In the reference it says the following about the gravity:

_"If this layout [LinearLayout] has a VERTICAL orientation, this controls where all the child views are placed if there is extra vertical space. If this layout has a HORIZONTAL orientation, this controls the alignment of the children."_

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity%28int%29

Comment: I used android:gravity="center_horizontal" as a last resort to center the layout on the emulator. It wasn't part of my code (I found it in some  topic of stackoverflow). I kept it in the code to show that it doesn't work either...

Comment: You could try putting another LinearLayout inside the one you have and have this inner LinearLayout have horizontal orientation with gravity center_horizontal. Then put the chess board inside this inner LinearLayout.

Comment: That sounds very clever. I will try and let you know...

Comment: Well I tried your solution and it did not work. However following your earlier comment I used android:gravity="center_horizontal" in all nested LinearLayouts with horizontal orientation and VOILA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried William's solution and it did not work. However following his earlier comment I used android:gravity="center_horizontal" in all nested LinearLayouts with horizontal orientation and VOILA! it worked.
Regards and thank you for all contributors...